# Self-connecting via SSH on GitHub Actions

Tags: ssh, github-actions

I cannot find a way to use the running SSH server on GH Actions.
When I try to connect to `127.0.0.1` via ssh, there is a server, and responds, but
somehow ignores the configuration files in `.ssh` (or whatever the case may be).

Here is what script I used (the general setup does not seem to influence the results):

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/whatever -N ''
cat > ~/.ssh/config <<EOF
Host host.example
    User $USER
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/whatever
EOF
echo -n 'from="127.0.0.1" ' | cat - ~/.ssh/whatever.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' host.example id
```

I am not satisfied with the results, since I cannot reproduce the log locally
(every machine I have behaves normally, i.e. allows to execute the command).

```
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Created directory '/home/runner/.ssh'.
Your identification has been saved in /home/runner/.ssh/whatever.
Your public key has been saved in /home/runner/.ssh/whatever.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:2ZCprVg5rZXp0IguQlCanUVTlCX7IFt2TPTnimdk0gM runner@fv-az60
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|  ..+o+++        |
| = o ..= +       |
|+ o . = E . .    |
|.    * @ O o     |
| .  o B S * .    |
|.  . o B = o     |
|. . o o o +      |
| . .     o       |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
runner@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
##[error]Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Comment: Could you run "ls -la" on your .ssh directory and [edit] the question to include the output?

Comment: It is empty before, confirmed by the `Created directory '/home/runner/.ssh'.` message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a permissions issue.  By default, the permissions on the home folder in the container are too broad for the ssh daemon to accept (world/others read/write), so the server-side rejects your connection.  Removing world/others read/write permission on your home directory fixes ths issue.

To fix, add the following to your script, just before the ssh call.  This command removes the others read/write permission on the home directory:

```sh
chmod og-rw ~
```

Evidence:

```
name: ssh-example
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/whatever -N ''
        cat > ~/.ssh/config <<EOF
          Host host.example
           User $USER
           HostName 127.0.0.1
           IdentityFile ~/.ssh/whatever
        EOF
        echo -n 'from="127.0.0.1" ' | cat - ~/.ssh/whatever.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
        echo "Before fixing permissions on authorized_keys, notice home directory is world read/write"
        ls -la ~/.ssh
        ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' host.example id || echo "ssh failed as expected... trying to fix permissions"
        chmod og-rw ~
        echo "After fixing permissions on home folder ~ ..."
        ls -la ~/.ssh
        ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' host.example id
```

Output from the Github Action:

```
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Created directory '/home/runner/.ssh'.
Your identification has been saved in /home/runner/.ssh/whatever.
Your public key has been saved in /home/runner/.ssh/whatever.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:vKl342+LK4YP7Kj00Eqm1Jnst/7ED3Pzu/6TPOiHoUc runner@fv-az76
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|       .         |
|        S        |
|  o.o..  o E     |
| .==. o*ooo = .  |
|.=.+ +ooO.==.*   |
|. oo=o==.=B@Boo  |
+----[SHA256]-----+
Before fixing permissions on authorized_keys, notice home directory is world read/write
total 24
drwx------ 2 runner docker 4096 Feb 23 21:58 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 runner docker 4096 Feb 23 21:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  113 Feb 23 21:58 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   89 Feb 23 21:58 config
-rw------- 1 runner docker  411 Feb 23 21:58 whatever
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   96 Feb 23 21:58 whatever.pub
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
runner@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
ssh failed as expected... trying to fix permissions
After fixing permissions on home folder ~ ...
total 28
drwx------ 2 runner docker 4096 Feb 23 21:58 .
drwx--x--x 8 runner docker 4096 Feb 23 21:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  113 Feb 23 21:58 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   89 Feb 23 21:58 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  222 Feb 23 21:58 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 runner docker  411 Feb 23 21:58 whatever
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   96 Feb 23 21:58 whatever.pub
uid=1001(runner) gid=115(docker) groups=115(docker)
```

Comment: Wow, I did not even think of it; it works, thanks. Shouldn't ssh tell what is wrong in some way? Like in sshd logs or wherever.

Comment: Yes, @Arusekk, usually there is a very clear error message in the sshd logs.  Unfortunately, I do not know the location of the sshd logs inside the server environment provided by Github Actions.    On my traditional system, the sshd logs record: `Feb 25 06:29:49 hostname.local sshd[503891]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/testuser`

Answer (score 0):

Permission Denied can be caused by multiple reasons.
this is code from [github repo](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/84226b447d45fe4542613de68c2ca59a890d7c01/mux.c#L443)

```c
    if (options.control_master == SSHCTL_MASTER_ASK ||
        options.control_master == SSHCTL_MASTER_AUTO_ASK) {
        if (!ask_permission("Allow shared connection to %s? ", host)) {
            debug2("%s: session refused by user", __func__);
            reply_error(reply, MUX_S_PERMISSION_DENIED, rid,
                "Permission denied");
```

this is caused by refused connection

probable causes.

1. sshd daemon i.e. ssh server is not running
2. user has no permission to ssh.
3. only root has permission to ssh.

check

`# systemctl status sshd.service |grep Active`

also check

`# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I don't think .ssh permissions are issue.
as they are created by user.
user permission mask is mostly 755. which is why not having permission for same user 
to its own .ssh directory is highly unlikely.

Do let me know if problem persists.

Comment: the protocol documentation link for [reference](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/dba50258333f2604a87848762af07ba2cc40407a/PROTOCOL.mux)